# Why does a second if work when an else doesn't? (PHP)

Tags: php, if-statement

Can anyone explain why this:

```
if($xml->$ul !== ""){
echo $xml->$ul;
}
if($xml->$ul == ""){
echo "0";
}
```

does work, while

```
if($xml->$ul !== ""){
    echo $xml->$ul;
}else{
    echo "0";
}
```

does not work?
Am i missing something?

Short explanation: if the xml contains $ul it will echo its value, if it is not contained it will echo 0. Works perfectly with first code, but second code just echos the values, the else is completely ignored.

I appreciate all answers!

Comment: What do you mean by "it works"? With what values are you getting unexpected behaviour?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, the see the answer below, i just got confused with the difference between === and == (thought it was just some weird php syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing the same equality check. In the first example you are first checking using `!==`, then in the second `if` you are using `==`.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80649/3166303) for an explanation of the difference between `===` equality and `==` equality. In short, `===` not only checks the values are equal, but also that the types of the variables being compared are the same as well.

Comment: Ah thank you for the link! I did not know there is even a === check (this is my first time with php). Changing the if to `if ($xml->$ul != "")` made the version with else work :)